# How to Instantiate in Edit mode and Destroy in Play mode, and visa versa?

Tags: unity

I am stumped on what feels like should be a trivial task:

Make a prefab with a script that runs in Edit mode AND Play mode that will spawn ONE and ONLY ONE child game object on Awake.

When you drop an Instance of the prefab in the scene in edit mode, it should immediately spawn the child game object. When you then press play, it should destroy that instance and create a new one. When you exit play mode, it should destroy that instance and create a new one.

BUT what actually happens when you enter and exit play mode a few times is you end up with multiple child game objects, despite the script pretty clearly always destroying the existing one before spawning a new one.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class PieceSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;

[SerializeField] private GameObject instance;

private void Awake()
{
    SpawnPiece();
}

private void SpawnPiece()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        if (Application.isEditor)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(instance);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(instance);
        }
    }

    instance = Instantiate(prefab, transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Is it possible you had a child object created before adding the `[SerializeField]` flag to save it, so its presence got recorded in the scene hierarchy while the script's `instance` member stayed null?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't think so. The child-parent relationship isn't actually known by the script. You could remove the "transform" argument from the Instantiate function call and it wouldn't make a difference. I've also tried with and without the [SerializeField] tag with same results.

Comment: What I'm saying is that when I use this code as you've shared it, I do not see duplication of the object. The destruction occurs as expected. Are you able to walk through the exact steps you take to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project? That includes the sequence of when you attach the script, assign the prefab, reload the scene, etc. It's possible you're triggering an edge case that I managed to avoid because I did the steps in a different order.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? State from Play mode is already erased when you stop the scene and return to Edit mode.

Comment: @Kevin I need something to get instantiated once and only once, either at edit time or at runtime. If the instantiation happened in editor, then I don't want it to happen at run-time. (I have object that can be place in the scene or spawned later, and in either case they need to select from a list of options for game objects to spawn.)

Comment: @BenMora The use case you are describing doesn't make sense to me. If you want to have one instance of a particular prefab in your scene, just put one instance of a particular prefab in your scene instead of creating a `PieceSelector` to Instantiate the piece every time you enter or exit play mode. If you want to spawn it later, don't put it in the scene, just spawn it later (or put it in the scene inactive, and activate it later). From the limited info you've given, it seems like `PieceSelector` doesn't accomplish anything other than making the scene take longer to load.

Comment: Looking at it from another angle; is there a reason you're destroying and recreating the instance instead of doing this: `if (instance == null) instance = Instantiate(prefab, transform);`?